# wordpress can alignwide image be fullscreen on mobile only?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using Wordpress Gutenberg image blocks with align wide. Ideally, I would like them to be edge-to-edge on mobile (like the alignfull style). I've tried playing with removing the padding and margins from everything I can find, but still get a small margin unless I remove all margins/padding from the site-content div (which puts the text against the viewport edges as well.

[a sample page](https://theslowroad.org/turning-laotians-readers/)

This CSS won't work, but I'm not sure why:

```
.site-content > *:not( .alignwide ):not( .alignfull ) {padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this may be a better approach.  In a media query targeting mobile, you want to target the class .entry-content .alignwide so that you override what is already in place.

Try this:

```
.entry-content .alignwide {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
    width: 100vw;
}
```